# Frame Navigation in Silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, navigation, tabcontrol, frames

I have a WebRibbon control for a menu. I have a TabControl on the page that holds all content. As you click on a menu I create a TabItem, add a frame to the tab item, navigate to a specific xaml page in that frame and then add the frame to the tab item. It works fine for the first page. The content of the xaml page displays correctly in the frame. A problem arise as soon as I navigate to a second and third page. All the frames on all the tab items navigate to the last selected menu items corresponding xaml content.

Comment: frame1.JournalOwnership = JournalOwnership.OwnsJournal;

This solved my problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

frame1.JournalOwnership = JournalOwnership.OwnsJournal;

This solved my problem...